# create-react-app and lite-server

Tags: reactjs, lite-server, create-react-app

So I working using ftp and so I can't use their npm start which is only localhost. I'm trying to run create-react-app with lite-server but am unsure of how to configure it so I can access the correct folder.

I've tried soft linking the `build` folder, but all there is, is a blank page with console errors.

This is my `bs-config.js` file

```
module.exports = 
{
    "files": ["./build/*.{html, htm, css, js}"],
    "server": { "baseDir": "./" }
}
```

So when I first run the lite-server I get a `200 GET /` then a `304 GET /index.html` However I then get the three errors:

```
404 GET /reactjs/build/static/js/main.9c645ba0.js
404 GET /reactjs/build/static/css/main.9a0fe4f1.css
404 GET /reactjs/build/static/js/main.9c645ba0.js
```

The files are obviously there, but I'm not sure how to configure lite-server to read those files properly.

Answer (score 0):

you need next setting for react project which created with create-react-app for example:

```
  module.exports = {
    "port": 3000,  
    "notify": false, 
    "ui": false, 
    "files":  "*.none", 
    "server": { "baseDir": "./build" }
   };
```